# How to not add to list after 10

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
<div id=leaderboard class="panel hidden">
    <h1>Leaderboard</h1>
    <ol id=top10>
        <li>Jyn Erso</li>
        <li>Mon Mothma</li>
        <li class="me">Han Solo</li>
        <li>Galen Erso</li>
        <li>Thane Kyrell</li>
        <li>Norra Wexley</li>
        <li>Ciena Ree</li>
        <li>Malakili</li>
       <li>R5-D4</li>
   </ol>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function updateLeaderBoard(arr, me) {
    let players = document.getElementById("top10");
    players.textContent = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i]));
        players.insertBefore(li, players.firstChild);
        if (arr[i].includes(me)) li.classList.add("me");
     }
}
list = ["Jack", "Robo", "Tom", "Dave", "Rock", "Agent", "Ops", "Recon","The Division", "Fallout"];   

updateLeaderBoard(list, "Jack");
```

I want to limit the names to the list to 10 even if it is more than 10 in the array. It should not add more if it is 10.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe try changing this `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) `?

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < Math.min(arr.length, 10); i++)` ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just put a condition in the loop- proceed only while `i` is less than the array length and less than `10`.

```
for (let i = 0; i < a.length && i < 10; i++)
```

If you're a beginner, this is an interesting learning point- sometimes beginners see the 'standard' invocation of a for-loop as some like of magic incantation that you can't change :) But of course, you can make the expression anything you like to change the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

*"I want to limit the names to the list to 10 even if it is more than 10 in the array. It should not add more if it is 10."*

You can achieve this using `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length && i < 10; i++) {...}`, where `i < 10` statement will limit iteration count to 10.